# Consuming wcf service Windows Form Application

Tags: c#, wcf, ado.net

I am consuming Wcf Service in Windows Form Application . I am trying to create user login system based on user emu type from sql database .When I enter the value 1 into textbox it should return full time employee method else value 2 into textbox it should return part time employee method but Its is not working according expectation ..

Here is Employee class code ....

```
    [KnownType(typeof(FullTimeEmployee))]
    [KnownType(typeof(PartTimeEmployee))]
    [DataContract(Namespace = "http://pragimtech.com/Employee")]
    public class Employee
    {
        private int _id;
        private string _name;
        private string _gender;
        private DateTime _dateOfBirth;

        [DataMember(Order = 1)]
        public int Id
        {
            get { return _id; }
            set { _id = value; }
        }

        [DataMember(Order = 2)]
        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set { _name = value; }
        }

        [DataMember(Order = 3)]
        public string Gender
        {
            get { return _gender; }
            set { _gender = value; }
        }

        [DataMember(Order = 4)]
        public DateTime DateOfBirth
        {
            get { return _dateOfBirth; }
            set { _dateOfBirth = value; }
        }

        [DataMember(Order = 5)]
        public EmployeeType Type { get; set; }
    }
    [DataContract(Name = "EmployeeType")]
    public enum EmployeeType
    {
        [EnumMember]
        FullTimeEmployee = 1,
        [EnumMember]
        PartTimeEmployee = 2
    }
}
```

Here is my Full time and part time employee class inherit from Employee class...

```
     public class FullTimeEmployee : Employee
        {
            public int AnnualSalary { get; set; }
        }
      public class PartTimeEmployee : Employee
        {
            public int HourlyPay { get; set; }
            public int HoursWorked { get; set; }
        }
```

Here is Method to Get Employee method to access employee based on employee type...

```
 public Employee GetEmployee(int Id)
        {
            Employee employee = null;
            string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spGetEmployee1", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                SqlParameter parameterId = new SqlParameter();
                parameterId.ParameterName = "@EmployeeType";
                parameterId.Value = Id;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterId);
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    if ((EmployeeType)reader["EmployeeType"] == EmployeeType.FullTimeEmployee)
                    {
                        return employee;
                       }                    }
                    else if ((EmployeeType)reader["EmployeeType"] == EmployeeType.PartTimeEmployee)
                    {

                        return employee;
                       }
                }
            }
            return employee;
        }
```

Here is my Windows Form Application ......

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MyService.HalifaxServiceClient myservice = new MyService.HalifaxServiceClient("NetTcpBinding_IHalifaxService");
            MyService.Employee employee = myservice.GetEmployee(Convert.ToInt32(txt1.Text));
            MyService.FullTimeEmployee ft = new MyService.FullTimeEmployee();

            if (employee == myservice.GetEmployee(Convert.ToInt32(txt1.Text).CompareTo(employee.Type)))
            {
                FulltimeEmployeeLinkActivites();
            }
            else if (employee == myservice.GetEmployee(Convert.ToInt32(txt1.Text).CompareTo(employee.Type)))
            {

                PartTimeEmployeeActivities();
            }
            else
            {
                label4.Text = "No infomation found";
            }


        }
```

Here is screen shot when I run the application ...[image: Click here to see the application]

Comment: How can i delete this question ??

Comment: Why this questions was voted down ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I see with your if / else is that the conditional statements are exactly the same.  One way that you can branch based on the type of an object is with the `is` keyword.

```
if (employee is FullTimeEmployee) 
{
    FulltimeEmployeeLinkActivites();
}
else if (employee is PartTimeEmployee)
{
    PartTimeEmployeeActivities();
}
else
{
    label4.Text = "No information found";
}
```

I would also add that this is not necessarily best practice, however it should get you what you are asking for.

In addition to that, your method that returns the employee instance never returns an employee of a valid type.  It doesn't appear that the `GetEmployee` method ever instantiates an employee instance.  It looks like it is always returning null.  Try returning instances of the proper type.  You will also need to populate the instances with the data you need.

```
if ((EmployeeType)reader["EmployeeType"] == EmployeeType.FullTimeEmployee)
{
    return new FullTimeEmployee();
}
else if ((EmployeeType)reader["EmployeeType"] == EmployeeType.PartTimeEmployee)
{
    return new PartTimeEmployee();
}
```

Comment: In that case your method that returns Employee is not returning an employee of the correct type.

Answer (score 0):

You have a confusing naming in your elements and "employee" class does not seems to be populated in your data reader.

"FullTimeEmployee" is the name one of your classes and also the name of one of your enums. So is not safe to set your condition

```
(EmployeeType)reader["EmployeeType"] == EmployeeType.FullTimeEmployee
```

I can not be sure without the code of your spGetEmployee, but if it returns values from your table with those same names it could be safer to declare

```
while(reader.Read())
{
    employee= new employee();
    employee.Id= reader.GetInt32(0);
    employee.Name= reader.GetString(1);
    ...
    employee.EmployeeType=(EmployeeType)reader.GetInt32(4);

    if(employee.EmployeeType== EmployeeType.FullTimeEmployee)
    {
        //Do extra work for this type of employee
        ...
        return employee;
    }

}
```

Comment: It smells wrong. You are returning a column of int value with the same values that you are passing as argument, not an employee record or its Id.  So expect always return the same value that you are asking.

Comment: Your mistake is that you are passing the Employee Id to the function GetEmployee and then using the Id in a store procedure that only compairs it with EmployeeType. Your sp should be something like SELECT * FROM tblEmployee WHERE Id=@EmployeeId

Comment: method name expected in reader(0); here ..which method name is expecting

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153646/discussion-between-fidel-orozco-and-rasel).